# Running dockerized Behat BDD Tests using Zalenium ( scalable selenium grid )

Tags: selenium, docker-compose, behat, zalenium

I am trying to Run Behat BDD Tests using docksal/behat docker-compose ( ref: https://github.com/docksal/behat

Looking at the Zalenium [documentation](https://github.com/zalando/zalenium)

```
Pull docker-selenium
    docker pull elgalu/selenium

# Pull Zalenium
docker pull dosel/zalenium

# Run it!
docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -v /tmp/videos:/home/seluser/videos \
  --privileged dosel/zalenium start

# Point your tests to http://localhost:4444/wd/hub and run them
```

integrating docksal/behat and zelenium is not clear

using. the. following docker-compose.yml

```
# The purpose of this -test example is for the e2e tests of this project
#
# Usage:
#  docker-compose -p grid up --force-recreate
#  docker-compose -p grid scale mock=1 hub=1 chrome=3 firefox=3
version: '2.1'
services:
  hub:
    image: elgalu/selenium
    ports:
      - ${VNC_FROM_PORT-40650}-${VNC_TO_PORT-40700}:${VNC_FROM_PORT-40650}-${VNC_TO_PORT-40700}

  zalenium:
    image: "dosel/zalenium"
    container_name: zalenium
    hostname: zalenium
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - /tmp/videos:/home/seluser/videos
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
    command: >
      start --desiredContainers 2
            --maxDockerSeleniumContainers 8
            --screenWidth 800 --screenHeight 600
            --timeZone "America/New_York"
            --videoRecordingEnabled false
            --sauceLabsEnabled false
            --browserStackEnabled false
            --testingBotEnabled false
            --cbtEnabled false
            --startTunnel false

  behat:
    hostname: behat
    image: docksal/behat
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    # Run a built-in web server for access to HTML reports
    ports:
     - 8000:8000
    entrypoint: "php -S 0.0.0.0:8000"

#  browser:
#    hostname: browser
    # Pick/uncomment one
#    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    #image: selenium/standalone-firefox
```

I can bring up the following containers:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                  NAMES
9a1620da4c71        elgalu/selenium:latest   "entry.sh"               4 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        40001/tcp, 50001/tcp                   zalenium_52g9tn
82975a246be8        elgalu/selenium:latest   "entry.sh"               5 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        40000/tcp, 50000/tcp                   zalenium_fdCCbk
862017957ba1        docksal/behat            "php -S 0.0.0.0:8000"    2 days ago          Up 8 seconds        0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp                 behat-selenium_behat_1
2da2c165a211        elgalu/selenium          "entry.sh"               4 days ago          Up 6 seconds        0.0.0.0:40650-40700->40650-40700/tcp   behat-selenium_hub_1
10df443d8378        dosel/zalenium           "entry.sh start --de…"   4 days ago          Up 8 seconds        0.0.0.0:4444->4444/tcp, 4445/tcp       zalenium
```

now looking at [run-behat](https://github.com/docksal/behat/blob/master/example/run-behat) in examples directory:

basically executing

```
$docker exec $(docker-compose ps -q behat) behat --colors --format=pretty --out=std --format=html --out=html_report "$@"
```

I get an error:

```
Error response from daemon: Container 411c6b89d8f382a64ed567dbe4d02a2840f06d4778f1ce7bcf955e720d96ab02 is not running
```

whereas:

```
$ docker-compose ps -q behat
411c6b89d8f382a64ed567dbe4d02a2840f06d4778f1ce7bcf955e720d96ab02
```

Perhaps in behat.yml `wd_host: http://localhost:4444/wd/hub`

it should not point to localhost,  but rather the hub? since wd_host should point to the selenium grid running in the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
hub:
    image: elgalu/selenium
    ports:
      - ${VNC_FROM_PORT-40650}-${VNC_TO_PORT-40700}:${VNC_FROM_PORT-40650}-${VNC_TO_PORT-40700}
```

is not needed at all.

Just point your tests to the zalenium service, since you are using docker-compose.
`http://zalenium:4444/wd/hub`

Comment: if I remove elgalu/selenium: i am unable to start zalenium cluster,looking at. error log:
$ docker logs zalenium
Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4
-- LOG 10:54:23:171273933 Ensuring docker works...
-- LOG 10:54:23:246228848 Ensuring docker-selenium is available...
Seems that docker-selenium's image has not been pulled yet
Please run 'docker pull elgalu/selenium', or use your own compatible image via --seleniumImageName

Comment: You can use the env var `PULL_SELENIUM_IMAGE=true` to avoid the need of declaring the `elgalu\selenium` service.

Comment: I am now consistently getting the following error:
Unable to complete AJAX request. (RuntimeException) when I run the Behat tests